# Keeping Trailing Zeros from .doubleValue() in Swift

Tags: swift, double

I am working on an application that needs to do some displaying and calculating of Double types in Swift. The struct that I created takes a Double as a parameter, and since it also displays it, I would like to keep the trailing zero at the end of the value. However, I cannot seem to keep the trailing zero from being truncated.

Here is what I have been trying in a Playground:

```
let numberString = "-3.60"


// "3.60"
let positiveString = numberString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "", options: nil, range: nil)


// 3.6
let positiveDouble = (positiveString as NSString).doubleValue


// "3.60"
let positiveDoubleString = NSString(format: "%0.02f", positiveDouble)


// 3.6
let positiveDoubleWithZeros = positiveDoubleString.doubleValue
```

I keep getting `3.6` as the result, no matter what I try. What is the obvious part of the conversion that I am missing?

Comment: `positiveDoubleWithZeros` is a floating point number, and 3.6 == 3.60. If you want to display the number with two fractional digits, then use the *string*  `positiveDoubleString`.

Comment: @MartinR So I shouldn't really worry about the trailing zero in the double value, but rather just use the string value for displaying after formatting it with the trailing zero? That makes much more sense.

Comment: Yes. A double value has no "trailing zero". What you see as 3.6 in the playground is again the conversion of the floating point number to a string.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use NSNumberFormatter:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3
println(formatter.stringFromNumber(1.0000))
println(formatter.stringFromNumber(1.2345))
```

This example will print 1.00 for the first case and 1.234 for the second, the number of minimum and maximum decimal places can be adjust as you need.

I Hope that helps you!

Comment: Both NSNumberFormatter and `String(format:) can format a floating point number, so you can choose which fits your needs better. But that is unrelated to this *question*, which was why the the *final* number appears as 3.6 instead of 3.60.

Comment: Can any one tell me how can I change to a Double because I need to use it for calculations rather than printing